# Use of "X can be Y only if Z are"

Tags: grammar, verbs, repetition

Example:

> Your conclusion can be withdrawn only if your prior papers are.

Is repeating the verb at the end required? Like:

> Your conclusion can be withdrawn only if your prior papers are withdrawn.

One suggestion would be to replace "are" with "can", but this seems to change the meaning:

> Your conclusion can be withdrawn only if your prior papers can.

Comment: English allows you to drop (elide) most sentence elements where there is parallelism or duplication, so I think the first example is fine (although some people may be momentarily surprised by the way it ends, they should be able to quickly work out what words are to be supplied). But equally, it is fine to repeat the verb and may make it clearer for some people.

Comment: Changing to 'can' certainly changes the strict logical, if not the pragmatic, meaning. (1) Your conclusion can be withdrawn but only if your prior papers are also withdrawn. // (2) Your conclusion can be withdrawn only if your prior papers are able to be withdrawn. (Logically, this allows that if your prior papers **are** able to be withdrawn, you may withdraw your conclusion while not actually withdrawing your prior papers. In reality, this is an unlikely scenario.)

Comment: ***I can only be happy if you are***. Nobody would seriously contend that ***happy*** needs to be repeated there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repetition of “withdrawn” is not required in a more or less casual context.

But: **”Your prior papers may be published in the Annals. Your conclusion can be withdrawn only if your prior papers are.”**
Now it’s confusing — if they “are” what? Published? Withdrawn? You have to state which one it is.

To be clear and precise when every word counts, it is best to remove any doubts by repeating “withdrawn”.

Comment: Right. Conjunction reduction is an optional rule, which means it's available but not required under these circumstances. And every deletion removes information, increasing ambiguity. Leaving stuff in produces boring but clear sentences; that's the foundation of legal language.